# Detect if .swf has transparent background

Tags: java, php, python, flash

Is there a way to do this programmatically in PHP, Python or Java?

Use case:

- User uploads .swf through an upload form.
- Detect if it has a transparent background.
- If it does, change it to something else, e.g. white.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in java cause both swf and programming in java resides in different boxes. We can play a swf file through java but might not access its internal information.  Not sure about python and php.

Comment: Could you offer a bit more context? Are you talking about a stand along .swf file? Or a swf that is embedded in a web page?

Comment: I added a use case to the question. Hope it helps. Unfortunately what I have to deal with is raw swf file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very difficult to determine, because all SWFs are actually transparent (or they all *can* be) - it's just that they can contain shapes which cover the entire stage, which make them appear non-transparent.

To determine this programmatically, you'd need to loop over every shape in the SWF and look at it's bounds. However, that wont be enough since any shapes can be changed by ActionScript blocks and new shapes can be created at run time.

But really, making them transparent is the hard task. Since you want to make sure they're are non-transparent, you can just deal with this at display time - put a colored div behind the object or embed tag.

Comment: I guess there is no direct solution then. Thanks for this detailed answer. Also thanks to all others who wrote their answers.

Answer (score 3):

Probably impossible.  I suggest a checkbox on the upload form "This flash app looks best with a transparent background".

[Here](http://www.morearty.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2006/10/TransparentBackground/TransparentBackground.html) is a flash app that has
- a transparent background to start
- a slider that lets you adjust the opacity

As you can see it would be impossible to say "transparent" or "opaque"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't get the background alpha (transparency) of a swf file. what I would do if I were you would put the uploaded swf into a container swf (load the uploaded swf inside it) which only has a background color of your choice.

There used to be a php swf reader in [this link](http://www.sephiroth.it/swfreader.php). But I didn't see any alpha information in it aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is a bunch of compiled binary data. You *Might* be able to hunt down a third party library which can un-compile the flash file and get some of the data from the root movie scene, but it's a large stretch. As others have recommended, a checkbox during upload would be the best route to take.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read the .html where the .swf is placed and see if there is a parameter called "wmode" and is set to "transparent"

If that's the case you can get the html file and read it with Python, Java or PHP.

It's an ugly solution, but it's a solution.

PS: Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I need to deal with raw uploaded swf file. I updated my question with a use case.

Answer (score 0):

The swf files are handled by plugins running inside or outside the browser. There is no way to tell if a certain flash has or hasn't transparent background... i guess you can assume that all of them are transparent..